# Chisel.TestApplicationException: test application exit - exit code 139

Tags: chisel

I got the above Chisel crash and I don't know what it means.  Any ideas?

The circumstances are that I'm trying to increase the size of my designed memory system from 512KB to 1MB.  The 512KB version tests good.  Twice as many banks in the 1MB version, and I get the above weird error.  The 2MB version test compiles the C++ model then just hangs indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I learned over in the Chisel google group that this error corresponds to a memory access error in the C++ simulation.  Therefore I'm filing this as a bug in gitHub and including a full exposition of the error there.  Many thanks to the guys over in google groups.